# Bulk Insert Not working

Tags: sql-server-2012, bulkinsert

I have a Bulk Insert query as follows

```
BULK INSERT tmp_table FROM 'file.jrl' 
WITH ( 
              DATAFILETYPE='widenative' , 
              FIELDTERMINATOR = '~' , 
              MAXERRORS = 0 , 
              ROWS_PER_BATCH = 116064 , 
              ROWTERMINATOR  = '0x0a' , 
              TABLOCK  )
```

It is giving me following error

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 4, Line 1
>   The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

I am using `DATAFILETYPE='widenative'` , because my data contains some special characters like Ñ,Ã etc
For RowTerminator value I have also checked with '\n'

My column separator is **~**. Is there anything I have to change?
My sample data is as follows

12345  ~asdfdfdfd      ~                              ~               ~    ~         ~0000000000~                                   ~0000000000~          ~rrrrÃ±tttttt       ~

Comment: The error is rather clear - your table column is shorter than the value found in the file at row 1, column 1, ie `12345 `. Where is the table schema? And did you notice the extra space after the digits?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, 95% of the error messages BULK INSERT returns have very little in common with the actual cause.

Comment: @captainsac, have a look at this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c070fe13-7476-4a41-b9ac-08700448c174/row-terminator-error?forum=transactsql. Also make sure that the number of columns never changes in the file.

Comment: Lacking any other information I'd check the column sizes first. Besides, what may appear to be irrelevant may actually be correct.

Comment: @Alex what you posted simply proves that the input file wasn't correctly formatted. BULK INSERT isn't a CSV import tool, it a fast bulk import tool from files that *do* follow the format. SSIS should be used if any kind of transformation is required

Comment: Have a look at this as well: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28167140/Bulk-Insert-Problem.html

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, I cannot see anywhere in my links or in original question where a data transformation is needed from BULK INSERT. My links suggest two problems: incorrectly specified ROWTERMINATOR parameter or a "missing column" in the table due to an extra field terminator at the end of the row. I totally agree with the statement about CSV. Incorrectly formatted file is a very broad issue, while it is likely true, the above error message does not elaborate on it in sufficient detail.

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos It is exactly 5 characters: Varchar(5)

Answer (score 0):

Do you work for BioWare?

Anyway,
the problem here doesn't come from the row terminator. The error message tells you that the first error occurs at the first column, so there's a problem with your field terminator.

My bet is on the datafiletype. Try 'widechar' instead of 'widenative'. Native field terminator is \t, and using native will make the BULK ignore the FIELDTERMINATOR option.

WKR.